# RecyclerView get EditText and set TextView

Tags: java, android

I want to get the data I put inside the EditText and when I press a button and I want to add the data to the TextView.
I have done everything inside the `onBindViewHolder`

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull  ReyclerViewerAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            holder.txtTask.setText(tasksList.get(position).getEdtTxtTask().getText().toString());
        }
    });
    holder.edtTxtTask.setText(tasksList.get(position).getEdtTxtTask().getText().toString());

    }
```

This is the `ViewHolder` inner class.

```
public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            txtTask = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTask);
            btnSave = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
            parent = itemView.findViewById(R.id.parent);
            edtTxtTask = itemView.findViewById(R.id.edtTxtTask);

        }
```

And this is the data class

```
package com.example.todolistapp;

import android.widget.EditText;

public class TaskList {
    private String taskName;
    private EditText edtTxtTask;

    public TaskList(String taskName) {
        this.taskName = taskName;
    }

    public EditText getEdtTxtTask() {
        return edtTxtTask;
    }

    public void setEdtTxtTask(EditText edtTxtTask) {
        this.edtTxtTask = edtTxtTask;
    }

    public String getTaskName() {
        return taskName;
    }

    public void setTaskName(String taskName) {
        this.taskName = taskName;
    }
}
```

Here is the `MainActivity`

```
        RecyclerView recyclerView  = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewerTasks);
        EditText edtTxtTask = findViewById(R.id.edtTxtTask);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        ArrayList<TaskList> taskLists = new ArrayList<>();
        taskLists.add(new TaskList(edtTxtTask.getText().toString()));

        ReyclerViewerAdapter adapter = new ReyclerViewerAdapter();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.setTasks(taskLists);
```

Comment: what's your question? Are you getting some exception you can't solve?

Comment: When I add a data inside the EditText and press Save it doesnt load the text into the TextView

Comment: putting the edittext into the TaskList is a bit weird. Can you show your layout in the recyclver adapter, especially the onCreate ViewHolder